# Derivation of Quantifier Negation: $(\exists x)Px \vdash -(\forall x) -Px$

Tags: solution-verification, predicate-logic

I am trying to figure out the derivation of: $(\exists x)Px \vdash -(\forall x)-Px$

This is my thought process so far is to establish a contradiction on Px and -Px, but i'm struggling with an assumption to contradict to get.

Here's my though process so far:

$
(\exists x) Px\\
-Px\\
Px \wedge -Px\\
contradiction?
$

But Im not quite sure how to go from a contradiction on that to $-(\forall x)-Px$, I feel like it would just get me back to $--Px$.

Can anyone provide any suggestions or assistance on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l} #1 \\\hline #2\end{array}}$ That is almost correct, but a negation introduction subproof require assumption of *the position you seek to negate*.

That is: assume $\forall x~\lnot P(x)$.

> $$\fitch{~~1.~\exists x~P(x)}{\fitch{~~2.~\forall x~\lnot P(x)}{\fitch{~~3.~\boxed a~P(a)}{~~4.~\lnot P(a)\hspace{10ex}\forall\mathsf E~2\\~~5.~\bot\hspace{14ex}\neg\mathsf E~3,4}\\~~6.~\bot\hspace{18ex}\exists\mathsf E~1,3{-}5}\\~~7.~\lnot\forall x~\lnot P(x)\hspace{12ex}\neg\mathsf I~2{-}6}$$

Comment: Question: How do we discharge 3? It would seem that by introducing P(a) and contradicting it with -P(a), we'd then negate 3 and just put us back at -P(a)?

Comment: **Existential Elimination**. When you have an existential, $\exists x~P(x)$, and can derive $Q$ under the assumption of a witness, $P(a)$ (where the assumed variable $a$ does not occur free in $Q$), then you may infer $Q$ with that assumption discharged.  $$\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash \exists x~P(x)\quad P(a)\vdash Q}{\Gamma\vdash Q}{\small\exists\mathsf E}$$ Well, $a$ does not occur free in $\bot$.